# Do I use Open Graph tags in right way?

Tags: seo, facebook, open-graph-protocol

Recently I added share button's on my [blog](http://exclusive-paper.com/blog.php) but when I press the button to share in facebook the wrong picture shows. Can you check what is wrong?

...
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    ...

Comment: Please add the HTML (relevant head and body parts) to your question.

Comment: How to add code?

Comment: Copy paste it from your website and use the bracket symbol to mark it as code.

Comment: I edited your question. Well, I guess everything is correct. You need to rescrape it by Facebook.

Comment: [Check out this at stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351980/ask-facebook-to-re-scrape-url) or go to [facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. But since you implemented this feature after facebook already scraped your page, you have to rescrape it:

Check out [this at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351980/ask-facebook-to-re-scrape-url) or go to [facebook debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)